# how to set the memory parameter in a Gurobi model

Tags: python, gurobi

I would like to allocate a large memory for a model created using Python API. When I try to set `MemLimit` parameter, I do receive an error.

```
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB

my_model = gp.Model('myModel')
my_model.setParam('MemLimit', 1e+11)
```

```
gurobipy.GurobiError: Unable to modify parameter MemLimit after environment started
```

Could soemone show how to create an empty enviroment, set the memory parameter and then connect that with the model please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two default behaviors that prevent you from setting the MemLimit parameter in the the Gurobi Python API (gurobipy):

1. gurobipy creates a default Gurobi environment
2. You cannot set the MemLimit parameter once the environment has been created

There are two alternate ways to handle this:

1. Use an environment file: Create a gurobi.env file in your working directory that contains the line:

```
MemLimit 1e11
```

2. Use an explicit Gurobi [Env object](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/py_env.html) like this:

```
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB

e = gp.Env("gurobi.log", params={'MemLimit': 1e11})
my_model = gp.Model('myModel', env=e)
```